# Image lost transparent effect when stored in Table

Tags: asp.net, image, image-processing

I want store the image in SQL server table, and I successed but when I retrive that image on page, I found that the image has lost its transparency. The origional image is png/gif. I have resized that image in 100px / 100px.

I have used following code to resixe the image. It works but when it stores image in database it lost the transparency.

```
using (System.Drawing.Image oldImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(imageFile)))
{
    System.Drawing.Size newSize = CalculateDimensions(oldImage.Size, targetSize);
    using (System.Drawing.Bitmap newImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(newSize.Width, newSize.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
    {
        using (System.Drawing.Graphics canvas = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            canvas.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Transparent);
            canvas.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            canvas.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            canvas.DrawImage(oldImage, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0), newSize));
            MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
            newImage.Save(m, ImageFormat.Png);
            return m.GetBuffer();
        }
    }
}
```

Any solution????

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This one probably answers your question:

[Why does resizing a png image lose transparency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753968/why-does-resizing-a-png-image-lose-transparency)

As the above link suggests, you're not loosing transparency because the image is saved into the database. It's when you resize the image that the transparency is lost.