# Save an image in its respective format to a stream

Tags: c#, image-processing, system.drawing

I have a challenge that involves multiple parts, most of which I have no problem with. I need a function that reads an image stream, automatically resizes it to a specified size, compresses the image to a specific leve (if applicable) and then returns the image stream, but also keeping the original image format and keep transparency (if there is any.)

This involves a simple resize function, which works I have no problem with.

It involves reading the original image format, and this code seems to work:

```
// Detect image format
if (newImage.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg))
{
      //etc for other formats
}
//etc
```

Returning the image stream is where I'm stuck. I can return a stream with the compression, but it defaults to to Jpeg. I don't see where to specify the format. And when I do specify format by saving the image twice, I am losing the transparency.

I guess there are two questions:

1) If I resize the image, do I also need to rebuild the alpha transparency on a PNG?
2) How can I save to a memory stream in the respective format while keeping transparency when necessary?

Here's my broken code!

```
System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo[] Info = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters Params = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters(1);
long ImgComp = 80;
Params.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, ImgComp);

MemoryStream m_s = new MemoryStream();
// Detect image format
if (newImage.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg))
{
    newBMP.Save(m_s, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
else if (newImage.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png))
{
    newBMP.Save(m_s, ImageFormat.Png);
}

// Save the new graphic file to the server

newBMP.Save(m_s, Info[1], Params);
retArr = m_s.ToArray();
```

Comment: This looks interesting regarding losing transparency when resizing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753968/why-does-resizing-a-png-image-lose-transparency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I use, although I haven't tested with transparency. This keeps the image in its original format without the switch on raw format. The reason you are probably defaulting to jpeg is that `newImage.RawFormat` comes back as the guid for the format, but not the actual enum value:

```
    using (Bitmap newBmp = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height))
    {
        using (Graphics canvas = Graphics.FromImage(newBmp))
        {
            canvas.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            canvas.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            canvas.DrawImage(newImage, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), size));
            using (var stream = new FileStream(newLocation, FileMode.Create))
            {
                // keep image in existing format
                var newFormat = newImage.RawFormat;
                var encoder = GetEncoder(newFormat);
                var parameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
                parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);

                newBmp.Save(stream, encoder, parameters);
                stream.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

I just tested this with transparency on a png, and it did retain it. I'll file that under good to know (up until now, I have only used it for jpegs.)

Comment: What is `GetEncoder();` its not explained anywhere in the example. thanks