# Resizing a PNG in a UWP project without losing transparency?

Tags: uwp

I want to resize a PNG image that is transparent in a Universal Windows Project, but I lose transparency.
Similar to this article of the Stack Overflow website.
[Why does resizing a png image lose transparency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753968/why-does-resizing-a-png-image-lose-transparency) 
I have checked all the articles related to my question in Stack Overflow, but none of them have a correct answer.
Can anyone help me to figure it out?

```
public static async Task<BitmapImage> ResizedImage(StorageFile ImageFile, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{

    IRandomAccessStream inputstream = await ImageFile.OpenReadAsync();
    BitmapImage sourceImage = new BitmapImage();
    sourceImage.SetSource(inputstream);
    var origHeight = sourceImage.PixelHeight;
    var origWidth = sourceImage.PixelWidth;
    var ratioX = maxWidth / (float)origWidth;
    var ratioY = maxHeight / (float)origHeight;
    var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);
    var newHeight = (int)(origHeight * ratio);
    var newWidth = (int)(origWidth * ratio);

    sourceImage.DecodePixelWidth = newWidth;
    sourceImage.DecodePixelHeight = newHeight;

    return sourceImage;

}
```

Comment: Why would you want to resize the bitmap at all? You could easily set the Width and/or Height of an Image control that displays the bitmap. It would scale the bitmap appropriately when you set its `Stretch` property to e.g. `Uniform`.

Comment: @Clemens : The issue is not just showing an image. It is not that easy as you think...

Comment: I don't understand why transparency should get lost at all. BitmapImage supports transparent PNGs, and just setting the DecodePixelWidth and DecodePixelHeight properties doesn't change set. I've tested your code and it works for me, i.e. the bitmap stays transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're losing transparency because you're converting to a bitmap and bitmaps don't support transparency. You need to use a format that does support transparency.

Here's a piece of code that will take a PNG and resize it without losing transparency

```
private async void MakeSmaller(StorageFile inputFile, StorageFile outputFile)
{
    using (var inputStream = await inputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(inputStream);

        var softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();

        using (var outputStream = await outputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId,
                                                          outputStream);

            encoder.SetSoftwareBitmap(softwareBitmap);
            encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = 50;
            encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = 50;
            encoder.BitmapTransform.InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Fant;

            await encoder.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt, How can I test your code in the click event of a button and a png image located in the app storage named image.png?

Comment: "You're losing transparency because you're converting to a bitmap". Where is OP actually doing that? The code in the question shows usage of a BitmapImage, which does support transparency, even after setting DecodePixelWidth and DecodePixelHeight.